# I was trying to get EditText Value

Tags: android, android-edittext

i  Was trying to get edittext value on onClickListner()  but when i tried it  using this `

```
 typed  = editText.getText().toString();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,typed,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

it always shows  "" but when i use this code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               typed  = editText.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,typed,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

it shows the correct value ..why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

It is bcoz .

```
typed  = editText.getText().toString(); // It is Outside the listner
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,typed,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Here it is initialized on first time when your Activity or Fragment Load. At that time EditText is Empty But when you doing on Click at that time it is getting EditText value and showing you actual value. Which is shown in below code.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               typed  = editText.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,typed,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

**Note:-** OnClick is a listener and it perform when you click that View. So that method will be call whenever you are going to click that View.